# Joomla Force SSL in Entire site except 1 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, joomla

I have purchase and installed an SSL certificate on my server and everything seems to be working correctly.
I selected in Joomla Global Configuration -> Server -> Force HTTPS -> Entire Site. Now the site all works with SSL as expected.

But, I have 2 pages that needs to be in http because the remote call does not support https :(
I have been fiddling with joomla native .htaccess but I either get redirection loops or errors.

Could someone please help with the correct .htaccess code for force http in 2 pages?

Answer (score 2):

There is a component that can be used to enable https on specific pages of website only. Check this https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/url-redirection/yireo-ssl-redirection/.
This will make your work easy no htaccess required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I took a look at it and it feels like an overkill. Full blown component with tons of php pages to do maybe 2 lines of .htaccess

Comment: @Box you just need to install it at the backend and no playing with php codes. Anyways your choice but if you get any solution through htaccess then do post it here so that others can be benefited.